# What's the probability of an element $a$ being in $S$ where $S$ is a random set of elements.

Tags: probability

Let's say you have a set of elements $G$. Now we make a set $S$ by randomly picking $K$ elements from $G$. The catch is that each element in $G$ has a weight and the probability of picking the element is proportional to that weight.

I'd like to know what's the probability of a given element $a$ being in $S$.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I wasn't very clear in my original post. I will take an example to explain what I'm looking for. Let's say $G = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ with weights $0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4$ for the elements $1, 2, 3, 4$ respectively. Now a set $S$ will be selected compromising of $K = 3$ elements such that the relative weight of an element determines its chance of being in $S$. I'm interested to know the probability of a element 1 being in $S$ (but worked out for a generic $K$, $G$ and weights).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. From my interpretation, you say "the probability of picking an element of $G$ to be in $S$ is proportional to its weight". You then ask "is the probability of picking an element of $G$ to be in $S$ proportional to its weight?". — Well, yes, you just said it is? Please clarify by [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4202095/edit) your question.

Comment: OP, do we draw with replacement? I.e. can you pick the same element twice? In that case, @Christoph, the weight gives the probability at each selection, and OP asks for the probability of the element being in the full set $S$, I think.

Comment: @Christoph I disagree that a clarification is needed.  Although I could be mistaken, I think that the OP intends that when $K$ elements are selected, the relative weight of element $a$ determines its chance of being one of the $K$ elements selected.  I find that to be unambiguous.  Then, what the OP is really asking is: how do you mathematically express the probability that $a$ is one of the $K$ elements selected, as a function of $K$, a function of the weight attached to $a$, and as a function of the weight attached to each of the other elements.  Again, I find all of this unambiguous.

Comment: @Milten good question, for the OP to respond to.  Although normally, the idea that $K$ elements are selected is usually associated with drawing without replacement, the OP does need to formally say so.  My guess is that this is in fact what the OP intends.

Comment: @user2661923 You disagree that clarification is needed but express your interpretation with "I think that the OP intends …" and follow "what the OP is really asking" by a whole lot of guesses that are in no way written in the question. ­— Yes, clarification is needed.

Comment: Not allowed to answer, until you *show work* in accordance with [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  I suggest editing your question to explore the following idea: let $G = \{1,2,3,4\},$ let the weight attached to each element correspond to the element's number, let $(a) = 2$ [which implies that $(a)$ has a weight of $(2)$] and let $K = 3$.  Then, manually show work by manually computing the chance that $a$ is one of the 3 elements selected.  Your work, and any clarifications, belong in your edited question, not the comments.

Comment: @Christoph Very reasonable rebuttal.

Comment: @Christoph the problem here is that I am striving to meet the OP half-way.  It seems clear to me that the OP will be almost as much challenged providing clarifications as he will be attempting to answer his own question.  I surmised that the OP was initially deliberately vague because he was hoping to avoid grappling with the complexities required in simply resolving his question's ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I have updated the question with an edit. Please let me know if it still feels ambiguous. I feel that @user2661923 understood me!

Comment: Unfortunately, the edit didn't clear up the main ambiguity: what is the process of constructing $S$? You still just say "such that the relative weight of an element determines its chance of being in $S$", which then still answers your own question as I said before.

Comment: @Christoph I think I'm a little confused too. I will think about it and get back!

Comment: Let $p_a$ be the desired probability of $a$ occuring. You want $p_a=cw_a$ with the given weights $w_a$ and some constant $c$. For any process that picks each $a$ with its $p_a$ (be the picks dependent or independent), we can compute the expected number of total elements picked as $\sum_ap_a=c\sum_aw_a$. For the situation at hand, you already know the expected number of elements picked ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best interpretation of the question:

Each element $a\in G$ has a weight $w(a)>0$. From this we can attach weights to subsets $S\subset G$ by letting
$$
w(S) = \sum_{a\in S} w(a).
$$
Now we consider the collection of all $k$-element subsets of $G$, namely $\Omega=\binom{G}{k}$. On $\Omega$ we get a weight induced probability distribution. Let $S$ denote a $\Omega$-valued random variable, then for fixed $S_0\in\Omega$ we can define the distribution by
$$
P(S=S_0) = \frac{w(S_0)}{\sum_{S'\in\Omega} w(S')}.
$$
Now we fix $a_0\in G$ and ask for $P(a_0\in S)$. If $\Omega_{a_0}$ denotes the subset of $\Omega$ consisting of all $k$-element subsets of $G$ that contain $a_0$, then it should be clear that
$$
P(a_0\in S) = \sum_{S_0\in\Omega_{a_0}} P(S=S_0),
$$
since $S_0\in\Omega_{a_0}$ is equivalent to $a_0\in S_0$ by definition.

Hence, we get
\begin{align}
P(a_0\in S) = \frac{\sum_{S_0\in\Omega_{a_0}} w(S_0)}{\sum_{S'\in\Omega} w(S')}.
\end{align}
Let $|G|=n$, then in the denominator each weight $w(a)$ appears $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ times, so that the denominator equals $\binom{n-1}{k-1}w(G)$. In the numerator, each summand contains the weight $w(a_0)$ and for $a\neq a_0$ we get $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$ summands containing $w(a)$.

Thus, we have shown that
$$
P(a_0\in S) = \frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1} w(a_0) + \binom{n-2}{k-2}w(G\setminus\{a_0\})}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}w(G)} = \frac{w(a_0) + \frac{k-1}{n-1} w(G\setminus\{a_0\})}{w(G)}.
$$

In your example where $G=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with weight $w(1)=0.1$, $w(2)=0.2$, $w(3)=0.3$, $w(4)=0.4$ and $k=3$, we get
$$
P(1\in S) = \frac{0.1 + \frac{3-1}{4-1} \left(0.2+0.3+0.4\right)}{0.1+0.2+0.3+0.4} = \frac{0.1 + \frac{2}{3} 0.9}{1} = 0.7.
$$

In particular, the resulting probabilities are not proportional to the elements weights. We have $w(1)=0.1$ and $w(4)=0.4$ but $P(1\in S)=0.7$ and $P(4\in S)=0.8$.

Comment: Another interpretation would be multiplying weights instead of summing them: $w(S)=\prod_{a\in S}w(a)$, which would yield a different result. As long as you don't specify how $S$ is chosen precisely, these are just guesses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really appreciate it! Just a follow up question, is there an explanation how you took $w(S) = \sum(w(a))$? I'm not sure but I was thinking maybe we could take product since the probability must be proportional to the weights? I think I understand how to do it now, I'll try it on my own and see!

Comment: Oh just saw your comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer**, but merely a long-winded attempt to help the OP clarify his intentions.  I am going to explore the specific example that he referred to:

$G = \{1,2,3,4\}$ with relative weights $1,2,3,4,$ respectively.  This is similar to the relative weights that the OP suggested, and makes the math easier.

$K = 3$, so the example calls for forming a set with $3$ elements.

It is assumed that $a$ refers to the element $2$, and the question is what is the probability that $a$ will be one of the three elements selected.

**Note**: 
I (still) regard this question as ambiguous.
The algorithm that I will employ is simply one possible algorithm that might be used.  The OP will need to consider this **long-winded** response to see if it is consistent with his intent.

The relative chances of elements 1,2,3 being chosen are 
$T_1 = 1 \times 2 \times 3 = 6.$

The relative chances of elements 1,2,4 being chosen are 
$T_2 = 1 \times 2 \times 4 = 8.$

The relative chances of elements 1,3,4 being chosen are 
$T_3 = 1 \times 3 \times 4 = 12.$

The relative chances of elements 2,3,4 being chosen are 
$T_4 = 2 \times 3 \times 4 = 24.$

So, to normalize $T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4$, I will calculate 
$T = T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4 = 50.$

This means that the chances of (for example) elements $1,2,3$ being chosen are $\frac{T_1}{T} = \frac{6}{50}.$

Here, the only one of the four possibilities that excludes element $(a = 2)$ is the selection of elements $1,3,4$ which has probability $\frac{12}{50}.$

Therefore, the chances of element $a$ being chosen are 
$1 - \frac{12}{50} = \frac{38}{50}.$

---

I emphasize that the above algorithm is simply one possible way that the weights may be employed.  The question is, does this **arbitrary** algorithm represent the OP's intent?

Comment: Great, that's the answer analogous to mine where weights are multiplied instead of summed! :)

Comment: Yes!! You've explained perfectly! I was a little confused how this worked, but now it makes sense. Is it ok if I put a reference to your explanation in my question?

Comment: Note that also in this case, the probability of $a$ being in $S$ is not proportional to the weight of $a$: we have $P(1\in S)=\frac{13}{25}$ and $P(4\in S)=\frac{22}{25}$ but the weights of $1$ and $4$ are $1$ and $4$, respectively.

Comment: I'll try to get the general equation on my own. Thanks to user2661923 and Christoph for all your help! I'm sorry for the ambiguous question as I wasn't very clear in the concepts...

Comment: @B2VSi It is important to realize that there is **no right answer** here.  An **arbitrary** decision needs to be made about how to use the weights.  Summing them instead of multiplying them is just as reasonable.